# Allocating and releasing memory in different threads in Delphi7

Tags: multithreading, delphi, memory-management

I have a delphi7 program with two threads. If I alloc memory in the first thread using new(), can I release it with dispose in the other thread ? I also am using fastMM

Comment: Are you using TThread class?

Comment: Yes. My objects are defined as  TMyObject = class(TThread)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Dynamic memory is shared between all threads in the process.

You must make sure that the `IsMultiThread` global variable is set `True` at an early stage. Using `TThread` or `BeginThread` to create threads will set `IsMultiThread` to `True`. If you know that your code uses threads then you may as well set `IsMultiThread` to `True` explicitly during initialization.

Obviously the allocation must complete before you start the deallocation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all memory of the current process is accessible to all threads. But you should absolutely make sure that these calls are not made simultaneously or do not take place in the wrong order, because that is easily done with multiple threads whose execution time is unpredictable.